# Zend Join Left Warning: Select query cannot join with another table in /var/www/myiartz/library/Zend/Db/Select.php

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join, zend-db

I am trying to create this select query in Zend:

```
SELECT `receive`.`itemid`, `receive`.`room` FROM `tm_receive` AS `receive` LEFT JOIN `tm_rooms` ON tm_receive.room = tm_rooms.id
```

This is my Zend_DB_Table Select Object:

```
$select = $this->select()
     ->from(array('receive' => 'tm_receive'),
            array('itemid', 'room'))
     ->joinLeft(array('room' => 'tm_rooms'),
            'receive.room = room.id');
```

But I'm getting this error: `Warning: Select query cannot join with another table in /var/www/myiartz/library/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 1350`

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$database = Zend_Db::factory( ...options... );
$database->select()->from(array('receive' => 'tm_receive'),
        array('itemid', 'room'))
 ->joinLeft(array('room' => 'tm_rooms'),
        'receive.room = room.id');
```

The problem is when using `select()`, the results will be limited to that table only.